# Why is weight in a fluid not equal to the buoyant force?

Tags: free-body-diagram, fluid-statics, buoyancy, weight

We know that, weight is the normal force acting on us. And for this *'normal force'* to exist *'something'* has to be under us. My question is when we're in water on any other fluid, is *that fluid* that *'something'* then which exerts the normal force on us? If so, then shouldn’t the buoyant force acting on us be our apparent weight in the fluid then cz *that* is essentially the normal(upward) force acting on us in that fluid(right?) But it’s not. Bcz in books, they say that The buoyant force or weight of the water displaced is the ***'loss'*** of weight (aka weight in air - weight in fluid) not ***'the'*** weight (aka weight in fluid). But why is that?(you might think that this is a duplicate of another question asked here. But the answers given on that question didn’t satisfy me.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a normal force on an object submerged in water?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148112/)

Comment: Bob D not entirely

Comment: Specifically what doesn’t it answer?

Comment: In the link, the question is whether or not there is a normal force in a fluid. But I already know that there is. I wanna know where that normal force comes from? Is it the water molecules pushing on the body? If so then how do they do that? I also wanna know why the buoyant force is not equal to *that* normal force(apparent weight) but why does it reduce it. A bit like this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340363/why-isnt-the-apparent-weight-of-a-body-in-a-fluid-equal-to-the-buoyant-force-w?rq=1 . But I didn't understand the answers fully especially the reference part.

Comment: Weight is the force of gravity that earth exerts on a specified object.  This force is normally measured by placing a scale under the specified object in order to compress a spring.  The spring compression and the spring constant tell you the magnitude of the weight force.  The opposing spring force provides the normal force that you are referring to in your first sentence.  This means that weight is not the normal force acting on us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is when we're in water on any other fluid, is that fluid
> that 'something' then which exerts the normal force on us?

Yes, in the sense that the displaced fluid will exert an equal and opposite force on us as the force we exert on the fluid where our body contacts the fluid, per Newton's 3rd law.

> If so, then shouldn’t the buoyant force acting on us be our apparent
> weight in the fluid then cz that is essentially the normal(upward)
> force acting on us in that fluid(right?)

No, because the apparent weight of the object equals the net force acting on the object, not the buoyant force, per Newton's 2nd law.

First of all, I think you will agree that the apparent weight of an object that is floating partially or totally submerged is zero (appears weightless) and is therefore not equal to the buoyant force. A spring scale would confirm this. That's because the buoyant force acting upward on the object exactly equals the force of gravity (the actual weight of the object) acting downwards on the object.

*But the maximum possible buoyant force* occurs when the object is totally submerged, regardless of the weight of the object,  because that's when the volume of the fluid displaced is a maximum and the buoyant force always equals the weight of the fluid displaced. When the density of the object exceeds the density of the fluid, the weight of the object $mg$ will exceed the maximum possible buoyant force $F_B$ causing it to sink. Then the apparent weight $W_{app}$ will equal the net force acting on the object, or $W_{app} =mg-F_B$, as your books told you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So basically you're saying that the weight that we feel i.e apparent weight is *NOT* the normal force but rather it’s the net force? If so, then how do you explain an elevator accelerating upwards. The apparent weight in that scenario is m(a + g). So according to you, the net force here =the apparent weight = m(a +g), right? But how is this the net force? As far as I know the net force here is ma(bcz -mg and +mg cancel out. So according to you, the apparent weight here is ma(I think) but it’s not(Again I think). How do you explain that?

Comment: First of all, apparent weight is not the same as the weight we "feel". Apparent weight is the difference between the actual weight and the buoyancy force. It's not me saying so. Check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxYXSoj2wpU

Comment: Secondly, the weight we feel is not the normal force. What we feel is the pressure on our body due to the normal force. For example, the weight we feel is different if we stand on the ground on two feet, one foot, or the ball of one foot, though the normal force is the same in each case. Each feels different because the pressure on our feet is different.

Comment: So The apparent weight of a submerged body is the difference between the weight in air and the buoyancy force( I understand this part now). But then what's the weight that the body feels in this case? Also I still don't understand what's the difference between the apparent weight and the weight we feel. So it'd be really helpful if you cleared that up

Comment: First of all, do you understand and agree that when you float you "feel" weightless?

Comment: yup I do understand that. Because the weight of the displaced water is equal to the weight of the body. So they cancel each other out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130323/discussion-between-abdullah-chowdhury-rafi-and-bob-d).

Answer (score 1):

The weight in the fluid is given by the gravitational force minus the buoyancy force (taking both as positive). If both are the same (i.e. if the object has the same density as the fluid), the weight in the fluid is zero and a totally submerged object is neither sinking nor rising.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possibilities for a submerged object:

1. It is floating, with part of it above the fluid surface. In this case the buoyance force is equal to the weight of the object. As only part of the object is submerged, that means: the object is less dense than the fluid because the weight of the volume of the displaced fluid (the buoyance force) equals the object weight, even having smaller volume.
2. It is floating but on the bottom of the container. In this case the buoyance force is smaller than the weight. Part of the normal force is carried by the bottom.
3. The object is floating totally submerged but in an equilibrium under surface and not touching the bottom. In this case the buoyance force is equal to the weight of the object, and the displaced volume of the fluid weights the same as the object, they have the same density.